# Needs to show Monotone

Tags: sequences-and-series

While doing one of my works I need to show this expression is monotone(increasing).
$$e(2n+2)!\sum_{k=2n+2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$ 
I am sure this is increasing on $n$ because I explicitly computed  for $n=1$ to $10$. And observed it is increasing but I need to prove it.

I tried many process such as diving by another consecutive term and trying to get more than or equal to $1$. Next I tried by taking the difference. None of my process worked here.

If anyone could show this is increasing then I would be very grateful.

Comment: For EVEN $ k$, group the terms $(-)^k/k!$ and $ (-1)^{k+1}/(k+1)!$  together as $ k/(k+1)!$. Then do a term-by-term comparison of the series for $ n $ and for $ n+1$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate I didn't understand...

Comment: @user254665 what you mean by Even k, since k is integers. Please write more explicitly for me..

Comment: As in the first line of Omran Kouba's answer.But the Q is harder than I thought.His answer is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$
a_n
=(2n)! \sum_{k=2n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
=(2n)! \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(2k)!} - \frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \right)
$$

Clearly, $a_n > 0$ and
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{(2n)!} = \frac{2n}{(2n+1)!} + \frac{a_{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}
\end{align}

So
\begin{align}
a_n =\frac{2n}{2n+1} + \frac{a_{n+1}}{(2n+2)(2n+1)} \tag{1}
\end{align}

In particular
\begin{align}
a_n > \frac{2n}{2n+1} \tag{2}
\end{align}

It follows that
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} - a_n 
&= -\frac{2n}{2n+1} + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+1)} \right)a_{n+1} \\\\
&> -\frac{2n}{2n+1} + \left( 1 - \frac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\right) \frac{2n+2}{2n+3} &\hbox{by $(2)$} \\\\
&= \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(2n+3)(2n+1)} - \frac{(2n)(2n+3)+1}{(2n+3)(2n+1)} \\\\
&= \frac{1}{(2n+3)(2n+1)} > 0
\end{align}

So the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is increasing as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am confused, please check second last line. My computation differs with yours.

Comment: Anyways conclusion is true. I think computation brings 1 instead of 2 in last line. Once again thank you very much

Comment: Yes.There is a missing "-1" in the numerator of the 2nd last line.But it works anyway.

Comment: Can you explain or add more steps for the equation : 
$$\frac{a_n}{(2n)!} = \frac{2n}{(2n+1)!} + \frac{a_{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}.$$

Comment: @user254665,@Lusin, just a typo, it is now corrected, thank you.

Comment: I really want to understand this proof, but I have difficulty to understand the first step. Can you explain them!?

Comment: @hlapointe, from the definition of $a_n$ try to simplify $$\frac{a_n}{(2n)!}-\frac{a_{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}$$

Comment: How can you simplify
$$a_n=(2n)! \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(2k)!} - \frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \right)$$
into 
$$\frac{a_n}{(2n)!} = \frac{2n}{(2n+1)!} + \frac{a_{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}$$

Comment: @hlapointe,, just think $a_n$ has two more terms than $a_{n+1}$ then think what left if we subtract them..

Comment: @OmranKouba, do u have any idea where does it converse? Even though it is increasing my intuition says it converse.

Comment: @Toeplitz, if you mean "converge" it converges to 1, since $$\frac{2n}{2n+1}\le a_n\le 1$$

Comment: @OmranKouba, I'm sorry, it may very obvious that $a_n \leq 1$, but I don't see right way. Please little hint

Comment: @OmranKouba, I used estimation for the reminder for alternating series and i got $a_n \leq 1$, is it true?

Comment: @Toeplitz, yes that is it.

Comment: @OmranKouba, sorry for bothering you time and again, do u have quick idea to tell decreasing or increasing or neither of $$ (2n+2)! \sum_{2n+2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} + \frac{a}{2n+2}$$ for $a>0$. we already know first term is increasing and second term is decreasing, but what about sum. I'm sure it depends on a. Is there we can say it decrease?